# IndexableGraphHelper in Titan?

Tags: java, titan

I am wondering if there is an implementation of Blueprint's `IndexableGraphHelper` or equivalent work-around in Titan. During ETL, I want to ensure that I do not create duplicate vertices and my edges have are properly connected. So, I attempt to see if a vertex with the same key/value exists before creating as follows:

```
Iterable<Vertex> sampleVertices =graph.getVertices("MyKey", MyKevValue); 

if (!sampleVertices.iterator().hasNext())
{
    //create a new vertex here
}
else 
{
    for(Vertex v:sampleVertices)
    {
        sampleVertex=v;
        //System.out.println("sampleVertexID: " + sampleVertex.getId().toString());
        break;
    }
}
```

I am a Titan novice and have not used Java in several years. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no such "helper" methods for Titan.  You have to write your own `getOrCreate` function to ensure uniqueness.  This is a fairly common pattern in "bulk loading".  You might consider using [BatchGraph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Batch-Implementation) during your ETL process as it helps simplify the `getOrCreate` a bit and will help improve the performance of your load.  You also might find this blog post series on batch loading to Titan useful: "Powers of Ten" - [Part One](http://thinkaurelius.com/2014/05/29/powers-of-ten-part-i/) and [Part Two](http://thinkaurelius.com/2014/06/02/powers-of-ten-part-ii/).